# How do I format dates without padding the values?

Tags: functions, string

I was not very statisfied with the leading zero that I got in my insert-date function.

It looks now as `09 jun 2015`, instead `9 jun 2015`.

To solve this, I looked into the source code of [s.el](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-right-len-s) and wrote a function for it.

```
(defun insert-date ()
  "Insert current date 1 jun yyyy."
  (interactive)
  (insert
   (if (string-prefix-p "0" (format-time-string "%d"))   ;; Checks if there is a leding zero. 
       (s-right (format-time-string "%d") 1)             ;; If so, chop it off with the library s, then s-right. 
     (format-time-string "%d"))                          ;; If not (for example, 10, 12, 25, 31), let it so. 
   (format-time-string "%b %Y"))                         ;; Then the rest (jun 2015). 
  )
```

After some tweaking, I still got the same error that there is a wrong type argument in sequencep 1. But I couldn't figure out.

Anybody have the golden hint?

Comment: What not use `%e` instead of `%d`? As per the documentation for `format-time-string`: "%d is the day of the month, zero-padded, %e is blank-padded." And if you don't want that blank you can send it to `string-trim`. Also, if you look at the doc for `s-right`, the function signature looks like this: `(s-right LEN S)`. You have it swapped.

Comment: @nanny I'm aware of `%e` but it adds an extra space, which I don't prefer.

So `foo-bar (01-06-2015)` will be  `foo-bar ( 1-06-2015)`. Never knew I could send it to string-trim, but I need to check if there is any space. Thanks for the suggestion. And it seems I have swapped it, indeed.
Your answer was the right, it worked again.

Comment: I made an edit: you can always use `(string-trim (format-time-string "%e %b %Y"))`.

Comment: @nanny Thanks, that's even a better solution. I wished that you added it as an answer, so I could validate your answer as the right one. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Not a problem, just accept your own answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look in the documentation for `#'format-time-string` (try `C-h f format-time-string`), it explains `%d` and `%e`.

```
%d is the day of the month, zero-padded, %e is blank-padded.
```

But it also goes on to say:

```
Certain flags and modifiers are available with some format controls.
The flags are `_', `-', `^' and `#'.  For certain characters X,
%_X is like %X, but padded with blanks; %-X is like %X,
but without padding.
```

So let's try it!

```
(let ((time (date-to-time "June 9 12:00 2015")))
  (format-time-string "%-e %b %Y" time))
```

results in `9 Jun 2015`, with no padding at all.

The flag `-` is easier than trimming the string, as it also works if you want to use a numeric value inside the string, for example:

```
(let ((time (date-to-time "June 9 12:00 2015")))
  (format-time-string "%-e/%-m/%Y" time))
```

results in `9/6/2015`.

Comment: Even a better answer, thanks for that! I must looking up the documentation more often.

Answer (score 0):

The user `nanny` solved it with

`(string-trim (format-time-string "%e %b %Y"))`

I didn't wanted the `%e` becauses it added a space. But I never knew the function `string-trim` chops the spaces off.